# Get the sign on X, Y in console

Tags: c, ncurses

How to get the sign on X, Y in console.

Example mvprintw(1,2,"H").
and SOME_FUNCTION_I_AM_LOOKING_FOR(1,2) -> return "h".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chtype mvinch(int y, int x)` comes to mind.

From `man 3NCURSES inch`:

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>    #include <curses.h>
>
>    chtype inch(void);
>    chtype winch(WINDOW *win);
>    chtype mvinch(int y, int x);
>    chtype mvwinch(WINDOW *win, int y, int x);
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> These  routines  return the character, of type chtype, at the
>   current position in the named window. 
>   If any attributes are set for that
>   position, their values are OR’ed into the value returned. 
>   Constants defined in  can be
>   used with the & (logical AND)  opera‐
>   tor to extract the character or attributes alone.
>
> Attributes
>
> The following bit-masks may be AND-ed with characters returned by
>   winch.
>
> ```
>    A_CHARTEXT     Bit-mask to extract character
>    A_ATTRIBUTES   Bit-mask to extract attributes
>    A_COLOR        Bit-mask to extract color-pair field information
> ```